# ReactJS acting weird when rendering component

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, jsx

I've weird issue when using `map()` function when using it with ReactJS. I have array of 3 objects hardcoded into my App state and when i try to iterate throught each object I can see the data in the console. It looks like that `TrackList.js` is being rendered again and then spits an  undefined error.
Here's my main files:

`App.js`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import SearchBar from '../SearchBar/SearchBar';
import SearchResults from '../SearchResults/SearchResults';
import Playlist from '../Playlist/Playlist';
// import songs from './songs.js';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      searchResults: [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Roses",
          "artist": "The Chainsmokers",
          "album": "Unknown",
          "isRemoval": false
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "Fight Song",
          "artist": "Rachel Platten",
          "album": "None",
          "isRemoval": false
        },
        {
          "id": 3,
          "name": "Thunder",
          "artist": "Imagine Dragons",
          "album": "Evolve",
          "isRemoval": false
        }
      ]
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Ja<span className="highlight">mmm</span>ing</h1>
        <div className="App">
          <SearchBar />
          <div className="App-playlist">
            <SearchResults searchResults={this.state.searchResults}/>
            <Playlist />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

`Searchresults.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import './SearchResults.css';
import TrackList from '../TrackList/TrackList';

class SearchResults extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="SearchResults">
        <h2>Results</h2>
        <TrackList tracks={this.props.searchResults} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default SearchResults;
```

`TrackList.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import './TrackList.css';
import Track from '../Track/Track';


class TrackList extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="TrackList">
          {console.log("Tracks:")}
          {console.log(this.props.tracks)}
          {
            this.props.tracks.map(track => {
              return <Track track={track} key={track.id} />;
            })
          }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default TrackList;
```

`Track.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import './Track.css';


class Track extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.renderAction = this.renderAction.bind(this);
  }

  renderAction(isRemoval) {
    if (isRemoval) {
      return "-";
    }
    return "+";
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Track">
        <div className="Track-information">
        {console.log("Each track:")}
        {console.log(this.props.track)}
          <h3>{this.props.track.name}</h3>
          <p>{this.props.track.artist} | {this.props.track.album}</p>
        </div>
        <a className="Track-action">{this.renderAction(this.props.track.isRemoval)}</a>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Track;
```

`Console.log()`:

```
Tracks:
Array [ {…}, {…}, {…} ]
Each track:
Object { id: 1, name: "Roses", artist: "The Chainsmokers", album: "Unknown" }
Each track:
Object { id: 2, name: "Fight Song", artist: "Rachel Platten", album: "None" }
Each track:
Object { id: 3, name: "Thunder", artist: "Imagine Dragons", album: "Evolve" }
Tracks:
undefined
TypeError: this.props.tracks is undefined
```

Comment: Maybe check if this.props.tracks is undefined and just return null when it is. I'm not sure why you get an undefined here, but I know that React renders components a few times.

Comment: i found an issue. it was called by another component which i didn't listed, which i thought has nothing to do with it, because I didn't touched it when i  was working with App component state. thanks for quick replies

Comment: Awesome! Those problems where you think you checked everything except one place suck the most :D We’ve all been more than once.

Comment: yeah, i spent 3 hours before posting here. and then after 10 more minutes I found the problem myself :D

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing the `this.props.tracks.map(track => {` line with the following line,

```
this.props.tracks && this.props.tracks.map(track => {
    // code continues
```